# Opening file in read-only mode through Intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently making an app which download a file from a server and then open it.

I succeed to launch intent and open the file. However, I need sometimes to open this file in read-only mode, I did not succeed so far.

Here is my code :

```
var uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", lastSavedFile)
var openingDocumentIntent = Intent()
var fileMime = context!!.contentResolver.getType(uri)

openingDocumentIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
openingDocumentIntent.setDataAndType(uri, fileMime)
openingDocumentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

context?.startActivity(openingDocumentIntent)
```

I have tried many ways :

- FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
- Intent.ACTION_VIEW and Intent.ACTION_EDIT

Moreover, I have seen many people complaining about Microsoft Apps such as Word which does not handle opening file in Write mode but only in Read-Only mode.

Does anyone knows how to open a file in read-only mode? (no matter which app opens it)
And the opposite... How to open a file in write mode with Microsoft App? (e.g Word)

Comment: same problem for me any solution??? please

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your file read-only:

```
  val f = File("path")
  f.setReadOnly()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. It does not work. I can still modify app with some .doc handling apps.